# Factorialization in JavaScript only works with decreasing recursion, why?

Tags: javascript, recursion, factorial

The factorial function in JavaScript only works with decreasing recursion (i--). If I use i++ (Google Chrome), the function is invoked but no result is returned, almost as if I would have started an infinite loop. Where is the error in my code?

```
This code does not work:
function factorial(n) {
  if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    n *= i;
  }
  return n;
}

This code works:
function factorial(n) {
    for (var i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) { 
        n *= i;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens due to the fact that in your for loop condition you are doing `i < n` comparison. n value is rising faster than i value (since n is multiplied in each iteration, while i is incremented) thus creating an infinite loop. You can fix that by using a different variable to store the result in:

```
function factorial(n) {
  var r = n;
  if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    r *= i;
  }
  return r;
}
```

Described situation does not happen in the alternative version of your code (with decreasing iterator) because it's loop condition (`i >= 1`) does not use the n value that is being changed in each iteration.

Also please bare in mind that neither of the two functions that you have posted are recursive. These are both iterative (first one with an increasing iterator, and the other - with a decreasing iterator).

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation, why my code does not work in the way I intended it. Also, thank you for pointing out my misuse of the the term recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Your question uses imperatives-style `for` loop but you tagged the post with recursion. Are you looking for a solution that uses recursion?

Recursion is a functional technique for "looping" but we won't compute the answer using intermediate values like `r` and `i`. In functional style we also avoid mutations like `i++` and reassingments like `r *= i`. Instead, we encode our intentions in a more direct way -

```js
const fact = (n = 0) => {
  if (n === 0)
    return 1                // (base) n is zero
  else 
    return n * fact(n - 1)  // (inductive) n is greater than zero
}

console.log(fact(5))  // 120
console.log(fact(10)) // 3628800
```

We can remove the imperative-style `if-else` statement and replace it with a functional-style expression -

```js
const fact = (n = 0) =>
  n === 0
    ? 1               // (base) n is zero
    : n * fact(n - 1) // (inductive) n is greater than zero

console.log(fact(5))  // 120
console.log(fact(10)) // 3628800
```

Finally, we calculate using "increasing" recursion -

```js
const fact = (n = 0, a = 1) =>
  a >= n
    ? a                  // (base) a >= n
    : a * fact(n, a + 1) // (inductive) a < n

console.log(fact(5))  // 120
console.log(fact(10)) // 3628800
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining recursion so well on this example. Due to lack of knowledge I misused the term recursion.